# UIPickerView as inputView always shows gray background on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got a `UIPickerView` as the `inputView` of a `UITextField` and can successfully set the background on iOS 8:

`statePicker.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.25f];`

But on iOS 7, I'll be damned if every single thing I've tried from other answers just results in this:

[image: statepicker]

Thoughts?

Comment: What SDK are you using? I just tried this on iOS SDK 8.3 running iOS 7.1 and I'm successfully able to change the background color.

Comment: Base SDK 8.3, deployment target 7.0, no luck.

Interestingly, this USED to work but I have no idea what changed. git log doesn't help, either.

Answer (score 3):

Verify your UITextField does not have his `Appearance` value set to `Dark` in the attributes inspector, just below the `Keyboard Type` setting. If so set it back to `Default`.